# Getting runtime version of a Silverlight assembly

Tags: .net, silverlight, assemblies, versioning, version

I want to show my Silverlight 3 application's version number in the about box, but when I use a traditional .Net call like:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

I get a MethodAccessException on the GetName() call. How am I supposed to get the version number of my assembly?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
private static Version ParseVersionNumber(Assembly assembly)
{
    AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName(assembly.FullName);
    return assemblyName.Version;
}
```

or this:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); 
String version = assembly.FullName.Split(',')[1];
String fullversion = version.Split('=')[1];
```

From: http://betaforums.silverlight.net/forums/p/128861/288595.aspx

a post about it:

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/93400/214554.aspx

You can look at the js file I posted here: [Detect Silverlight version required by an assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862801/detect-silverlight-version-required-by-an-assembly/2219515#2219515)

Your error is expected.as it is secutiry critical, above are some work arounds.

Comment: GetExecutingAssembly also returns an Assembly type, its the call the GetName which fails.

Comment: that should get you through it, I just tested it and it works fine.

Comment: I like the first solution. It seems cleaner. Both do work, however.

Comment: +1 for the first excellent solution, although I'd return an assembly name and let the caller access the `Version` property.  The rest however is just awkard link heavy fluff, this answer would be way better and cleaner with just the simple first approach.  @Dov, this is IMO your answer.

Comment: Great solution.  The crazy thing is that assembly.GetCustomAttributes doesn't return the AssemblyVersion attribute -- it returns most of the others that I expected (company/trademark/etc)

Answer (score 6):

`GetName` is marked as Security Critical and hence you get an exception when you attempt to call it.

You will need to use the `FullName` property and parse out the `Version=x.x.x.x` part of the string.

Comment: they are really paranoid the microsoft guys aren't they

Comment: @herzmeister der welten: It would only take one minor hiccup in the Silverlight sandbox to do some serious damage to its reputation.  At this stage in the life of Silverlight Microsoft cannot afford any such hiccup.  I suspect that there are many things that don't actually represent a threat but because they aren't vital and haven't had thorough security anaylsis and testing they'll have the Security Critical attribute just to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
 .GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<AssemblyVersionAttribute>()
 .Single().Version;
```

Comment: GetCustomAttributes(bool) will not return AssemblyVersionAttribute, because it is treated in a "special" way. You can still use AssemblyFileVersionAttribute and it will work. Otherwise, thanks for the answer that does not include parsing strings :)