# Unable to call Assembly.GetName() from my Silverlight application

Tags: c#, silverlight, reflection, version, methodaccessexception

I want to display my application version number within my application, and the simplest way to do this is to use the version number for the assembly.

```
var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var name = assembly.GetName();
return String.Format("Version {0}.{1}", name.Version.Major, name.Version.Minor);
```

I can get the executing assembling without problem, but the call to `GetName()` returns a `MethodAccessException` with this message

> Attempt by security transparent method 'MainPage..ctor()' to access security critical method 'System.Reflection.Assembly.GetName()' failed.

Why is this happening, is there anything I can do about it, and if not is there another means of retrieving the assembly version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Assembly.GetName is marked with SecurityCriticalAttribute attribute try using `GetCallingAssembly().FullName` and scrape the version info out of it.

> Do not use this member in your application. If you do, your code will
>   throw a MethodAccessException. This member is security-critical, which
>   restricts it to internal use by the .NET Framework for Silverlight
>   class library. [SECURITY CRITICAL]

from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w2wdeze(VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 8):

I got this from Stackoverflow ([Getting runtime version of a Silverlight assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297273/getting-runtime-version-of-a-silverlight-assembly)) ... works for me:

```
    public static string GetVersion()
    {
        string versionNumber = ParseVersionNumber(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).ToString();
        return versionNumber;
    }

    private static Version ParseVersionNumber(Assembly assembly)
    {
        AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName(assembly.FullName);
        return assemblyName.Version;
    }
```