# How to get runtime version of Silverlight programmatically

Tags: silverlight

Is it possible to programmatically from a silverlight app to get the runtime information of silverlight?

Note: that does not include making a call out to javascript

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20722/version-detection-with-silverlight

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to get the runtime & build version for a Silverlight app from inside the app you can use the [Environment.Version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.version%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) & [Deployment.RuntimeVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.deployment.runtimeversion%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: My guess: Deployment.RuntimeVersion is the version that you use to build the Silverlight application (.dll’s in the .xap).
You can find this version in the AppManifest.xaml